# Why does a macbook running OS X 10.7.5 Lion automatically boot up at 9 seconds after midnight?

Tags: macos, boot

Why would a macbook automatically boot up at the same time every night even though it was shutdown by a user?

How can I disable automatic boots?

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Energy Saver > Schedule… > [_] Start up or wake [Every day] at [12:00 AM][image: Screenshot]

Comment: eh, perfectly good answer but got autoflagged for some reason. Maybe a screenshot to keep the cold unfeeling code happy? ;p

Answer (score 1):

You can also review the power management settings from the command line:

```
pmset -g sched
```

Will return a list of repeating and non-repeating events that are scheduled.

```
pmset repeat cancel
```

Will cancel any repeating events.